# Projective planes over algebraically closed fields

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, projective-geometry, incidence-geometry

Suppose I am given a projective plane $P \cong \mathbb{P}^2(k)$ over a (commutative) field $k$.

With "projective plane," I mean the *point-line geometry* (and not, for instance, the scheme): $k$-rational points and $k$-rational lines.

Is there a combinatorial characterization (only using the points and lines), which tells me that $k$ is algebraically closed ?

If I would have asked that $k$ is a division ring, then Pappus's Theorem tells us when precisely $k$ is commutative through a configurational property.

So I wonder whether similar things can be formulated for the case when $k$ would be algebraically closed.

Comment: In principle, yes, since one can encode algebraic equations using projective line arrangements.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Do you know a reference for that?

Comment: @arsmath It's in Mnev's proof of his universality theorem. I will add a reference later. Mnev works over the reals but the argument is general.